# Error when getting my Signed APK in Android Studio - Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio, mobile, signed-apk

When i'm going to create signed APK in Adroid Studio, this error happens..

```
Could not find com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.2.
    Searched in the following locations:
        file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        file:/C:/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        file:/C:/Users/pache/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        file:/C:/Users/pache/.m2/repository/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
        https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.pom
        https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/com/android/tools/lint/lint-gradle/26.1.2/lint-gradle-26.1.2.jar
    Required by:
        project :android
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try whit this

in your project`s gradle file add the following lines

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        .....
        ......
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }  
        ......
    } }
```

I hope it helps